# jqGrid: No such method: restoreRow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am having an issue working with jaGrid and ASP.NET MVC 2. Everything is working, but when I select a row I get this error on FireBug: uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method: restoreRow.
Debugin Js I realize that error happend here:

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
    if (id && id !== lastsel) {
        jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
        jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
        lastsel = id;
    }
```

I think, the problem is the jqGrid libraries include (or the include order). This is my Index.aspx page.

```
<%--CSS Files--%>
<link href="/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/ui.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<%--jQuery Library--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<%--Must load language tag BEFORE script tag--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/grid.locale-es.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/grid.jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/grid.base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/grid.common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/grid.formedit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.fmatter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/grid.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jqDnR.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jqModal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/grid.import.js"></script>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<table id="tableAccidentes" border=0>
    <tr>
        <td><img alt="" src="../../images/icono_victima.png" /></td>
        <td><h2>Accidentes Registrados</h2></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastsel;
    var Plantas = ['Pablo Podesta', 'Pilar', 'Tigre', 'Otra'];

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Accidentes/ListarAccidentes',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['Fecha', 'Detalle', 'Accidentado', 'Planta'],
            colModel: [
                { name:'Fecha', index:'Fecha', width:150, align:'left',
                  editable:true },
                { name:'Detalle', index:'Detalle', width:150, align:'left',
                  editable:true },
                { name:'Accidentado', index:'Accidentado', width:200,
                  align:'left', editable:true },
                { name:'planta', index:'planta', width:150, align:'left',
                  editable:true, edittype:"select",
                  editoptions: { value:Plantas} }
           ],
            onSelectRow: function(id) {
                if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                    lastsel = id;
                }
            },
            editurl: "/Accidentes/GridSave",
            edit: {
                addCaption: "Agregar Accidente",
                editCaption: "Editar Accidente",
                bSubmit: "Guardar",
                bCancel: "Cancelar",
                bClose: "Cerrar",
                saveData: "Se modifico el registro! ¿guardar los cambios?",
                bYes: "Si",
                bNo: "No",
                bExit: "Cancelar"
            },
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
            caption: 'Accidente'
        }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, search: false, del: false },
                  { closeAfterAdd: true, closeAfterEdit: true });
        // add custom button to export the data to excel
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager',{
            caption:"", 
            onClickButton : function () {
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('excelExport',
                                   { url: '/Accidentes/ExportarAccidentes' });
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<%-- HTML Required--%>
<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

Please, can someone help me?

Comment: Please never add new answer on your question if you want give me additional information. Just append your original question with new information and write small comment to my answer where you wrote that you changed your question. So I receive notification about new comment, can read your question and help you. Your new answer was just deleted. Now back to your deleted question. You continue to include minimized `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` **together** with uncompressed `grid.base.js` and other files. It can not work. You should remove either `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or all other js excepting "-es.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [restoreRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#restorerow) and [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) methods, which you use, are defined in the `grid.inlinedit.js` file and are the part of [the inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) module (see more in [the jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ahow_to_install#development_installation)). Moreover you should remove the file `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to avoid having definitions of the same functions twice. Because the method [restoreRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#restorerow) was not defined in the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` which you use you use probably wrong downloaded jqGrid version. You should download the jqGrid one more time and be sure that you check "Inline Editing" module. If you open `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` file in the text editor you will see in the comment at the begining of the file all modules which was the part of the download.

Some additional small remarks: in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) is described which parameters of the `colModel` are default. For example, `width:150` and `align:'left'` have defaout values, so you can remove there from the column definition.

The `value` property for "select" type of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions) which you use is wrong. The `Plantas` should be defined as

```
var Plantas = { 'Pablo Podesta':'Pablo Podesta', Pilar:'Pilar',
                Tigre:'Tigre', Otra:'Otra'};
```

or as

```
var Plantas = 'Pablo Podesta:Pablo Podesta;Pilar:Pilar;Tigre:Tigre;Otra:Otra';
```

See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions) for details.

The parameter `imgpath` is [deprecated](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aupgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5) and should be removed. Class "scroll" is also deprecated and the HTML fragment for the jqGrid can be reduced to

```
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

See an example [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file).

The parameter `edit` is not exist in the jqGrid it is the parameter of `editGridRow` from the form editing. You can define it as the part of `navGrid` parameters [prmEdit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) and [prmAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition). Currently you use only [prmEdit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition). Probably the usage of `grid.locale-XX.js` from the `i18n` directory will make the usage of `edit` parameter unneeded.